# How to send Json or "dict" using Django Messages Framework

Tags: python, django, django-messages

I'm using **Django Messaging** framework to send additional data on the validation error:

```
def clean_X(self):
        xuser_id = self.cleaned_data['xuser_id']
        if xuser.objects.filter(xuser_id=xuser_id).exists():
            available_now = {"available" : ["example","hello","ahc","sdcsd"]}
            messages.error(self.request, message = available_now,extra_tags="available_ids")
            raise forms.ValidationError('Sorry! User ID "%(xuser_id)s" is already taken, Please try another or chose one from following:', params={"xuser_id" : xuser_id})
        return xuser_id
```

The message is converted as a string when tried to access in the template: like

```
"{"available" : ["example","hello","ahc","sdcsd"]}"
```

making difficult to access programmatically i.e `message.available`

How can i send a json directly to the template using **Django-Messages**. My intention is here, not just to display a message rather make `available-id`'s clickable (like the one in gmail auto-suggestion of username)

Thanks!

Comment: I would write a custom template filter that converts the string back to JSON and parses it.

Comment: Thanks Selcuk for the response. I tried converting string back to json using filter : ast.literal_eval(dictionary). and it throws error: malformed node or string: <django.contrib.messages.storage.base.Message object at 0x7f090a5d64e0>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{% for message in messages %}
    <p>{{ message.tags }}</p>
    {% if message.tags == 'available_ids error' %}
    {% for obj,values in message.message.items %}
        <div>
            {{ obj  }} 
            {% for val in values %}
                <p class="user-id">{{ val }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

You can use above code snippet inside template to make it working and  modify it according to your requirements.

How it works?

We iterate through each and every message, as we have inserted dictionary in messages so we have to iterate dictionary and inside dictionary we have list so we have to iterate that too.
Therefore we have to use three for loop. 
You have to apply some conditions like when you have to iterate? You can check using this by tags.

**Here I have hard coded (iterating condition) for this purpose.**

Edit:

Using two for loops
Update your clean_X with these lines

```
available_now = ["example","hello","ahc","sdcsd"]
messages.error(self.request, message = available_now,extra_tags="available_ids")
```

and use these lines in templates

```
{% for message in messages %}
    <p>{{ message.tags }}</p>
    {% if message.tags == 'available_ids error' %}
        <div>
            {% for val in message.message %}
                <p class="user-id">{{ val }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks! Sonu Kumar!
Am just wondering, is this, multiple iterations on the template, the only way to handle this kind of problem?

Comment: I don't know. You  can accomplish same using two for loop.  see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

In `views.py`

```
def account_exists(request):

    error_message = {"for": "register", "type": "error", "msg": "Something wrong here, it may be that you already have an Account!"}
    messages.error(request, error_message)

    return redirect("register")
```

HTML

```
<div>
    {% for message in messages %}
    <script>
        message = "{{ message | safe}}"
        message = message.replace(/'/g, '"')
        console.log(message, typeof (message))
        json_message = JSON.parse(message)
        console.log(json_message, typeof (json_message))
        console.log(json_message.for)
        console.log(json_message.type)
        console.log(json_message.msg)
    </script>
    <br>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```