# How to use just one url pattern in django to handle GET, POST and kwargs in HttpResponseRedirect?

Tags: python, django, httpresponse

I know that after dealing with a post request we should not render the page but should use HttpResponseRedirect. I wanted to send some data back with this redirect. I went through multiple SO but I have few questions.

- Using message framework.
  Good until you are just sending text messages. If I want to send objects or dictionaries back to template what should I use?
- I came to know we can use `*args` or `**kwargs`.
  when I tried to use kwargs in HttpResponseRedirect, it complain about url matching. So does that mean I need to create another URL which accepts kwargs.

Lets see one example here:-
I am saving some data for which I have this url.

```
url(r'^add-event/$', views.add_event, name='add_event')
```

on GET request of this page, template is loaded which shows form to save the data.
On POST request of this page, form data is saved.
Now if everything is fine in POST request, I can send success message back with query string or with message framework. But if there is some error while saving data, I want to send whole data back to the template to render it into the form as it is so that user need not to fill the form again.

Here comes my question. If I use args or kwargs like below :

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("tenant:add_event kwargs=data))
```

where data is dictionary containing lots of data (not simple text message), How do I form the matching url?

Is it possible to make **just one** URL for GET and POST request and to handle the above scenario?

Comment: Don't try and pass complex data in the URL. Use the session.

Comment: @DanielRoseman : how can I delete/unset the variable in session after using in template?

Comment: Well you do that in the view, for example by using `pop`.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to your question about the messages framework take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35453079/how-to-send-json-or-dict-using-django-messages-framework) here describing how to pass a dictionary using the messages framework.

You can also use the django sessions [framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/) in order to save the POST data in a session.In that way the redirected page will have access to the data submitted by the Http POST.